# Trouble Resubscribing to observable

Tags: android, rx-java, viewmodel, rx-java2

I'm following Kaushik Gopal's implementation of MVI with a ViewStates Observable and a ViewEffects Observable. Example can be seen here: https://github.com/kaushikgopal/movies-usf/blob/master/app/src/main/java/co/kaush/msusf/movies/MSMovieVm.kt

Relevant snippet:

```
  init {
    eventEmitter
      .doOnNext { Timber.d("[Event]: $it") }
      .eventToResult()
      .doOnNext { Timber.d("[Result]: $it") }
      .share()
      .also { result ->
        viewStates = result
          .resultToViewState()
          .doOnNext { Timber.d("[ViewState]: $it") }
          .replay(1)
          .autoConnect(1) { disposable = it }
          .distinctUntilChanged()

        viewEffects = result
          .resultToViewEffect()
          .doOnNext { Timber.d("[ViewEffect]: $it") }
      }
  }
```

The major difference is that I'm using Fragments instead of Activities. Everything works the first time around, but when I go from Fragment A to Fragment B, then back to Fragment A, the result observable triggers new ViewStates, but no new ViewEffects. Is there a special way I should be subscribing/unsubscribing or am I constructing the rx chain in a strange way? I currently subscribe to both the ViewStates and ViewEffects Observables in `onViewCreated()` and dispose in `onViewDestroyed()`. I've verified that both Observables are subscribed to in each case, it's just that when I come back to Fragment A, and input new ViewEvents, I get new ViewStates but not ViewEffects. Maybe it's a multi-casting issue?

Comment: You are calling `.replay` in `viewStates` stream and not calling it in `viewEffects` stream.

Comment: This is because ViewStates should be replayed when a view attaches/subscribes, but ViewEffects should not. Say you rotate the screen. You want the same ViewState, but you wouldn't want to re-show an error message for example. Replay is also called after the result has been converted to a ViewState. The result observable doesn't even fire for ViewEffects, even though the view is subscribed to both Observables so I'm not sure how replay would help.

Comment: ^ Yes your understanding is correct. And the same thing that happens when you rotate the screen also happens when you go back from Fragment B to A as well. If you are using Android navigation component, fragment back navigation also goes through `onCreateView...onResume` cycle. Your view model is not re-created, and `viewEffects` does not emit again. The only reason why `viewStates` emits again is the `replay`.

Comment: But in theory i should be getting new ViewStates AND new ViewEffects if I re-subscribe and enter new ViewEvents. Currently, I only get new ViewStates when I re-subscribe and enter new ViewEvents.

Comment: Are you saying after the back navigation, "[Event]", "[Result]", "[ViewState]" is logged but not "[ViewEffect]"?  What happens when you rotate the screen, then enter new `ViewEvents`? Does this also cause the problem?

Comment: That is correct. Rotating the screen does not cause this problem.

Comment: Screen rotation and back navigation for fragments should be technically the same except few things. In which fragment method do you subscribe to the observables?